# How to install react on an existing react project using VSC but with a fresh OS installed?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code

When I started the project a while back from scratch all packaged installed successfully worked on the project for a while I used:

> npm create-react-app my-app

I re-installed my OS which is Windows 10 now. How can I start the same project again with out over-writing or changing anything from my project?

I tried

> npm start

and

> npm install --save-dev react-scripts

got the same error back :
npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Comment: After installing OS, did you install the npm package manager?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you first install node.js(npm package) & also JDK on your new OS. After that install react-native-cli globally. `npm install -g react-native-cli` .

After successful installation, you can create your new app. `npx react-native init SampleApp`.

Comment: the point is to avoid creating a new app and use the app i had installed already before reinstalling my OS

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

First I installed Node manually from the windows installer https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Then I ran:

```
npm install react
```

in the VSC terminal.

It took a little longer than usual for it to load up the page, but it did eventually. I'm not quite sure if there are any bugs my way, but at least got it to start. I will edit the answer, if possible, with updates if there is any problem that shows up. If you do this, make sure to....

Comment: "If you do this, make sure to..." - This is a worringly unfinished statement. Elaborate?